# How much more is '翻一番‘

Tags: grammar

I think this means 'double the sales volume', but 翻 can mean 'turnover' as in 'sales volume' or 'double'. '一番‘ seems to mean 'twofold'. I'm a bit confused.

。。。在未来十年内实现销售额翻一番， 。。。maybe = ...double the turnover in the next ten years ...

Which word is 'double'??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `翻` means `multiply`, `番` means `time;fold`.

And
`翻番/翻一番` -> *2(double)
`翻两番` -> *4
`翻三番` -> *8
... ...

Comment: @Pedroski Yes..

Answer (score 0):

I did some study on this. Here is my two cents.

番, Fan1, is a measurement word for a piece of sheet, for example, paper, gold sheet, or land. 金薄十万番, 吏以纸万番赆之, 一番江水一番鱼.

番，when used in calculation，means the base number. There are 2 cases: 加番，翻番. For example, if the area of a piece of paper is 100 square centimeters, then 一番 = 100 (cm^2).

加1番=100+100, 加N番=100+N*100.

翻1番=100*(1+1)=200,翻2番= 翻1番 and 翻1番 again. (100*(1+1))(1+1)=200*2=400, etc.

加 means to put in another piece of paper.

翻 means to turn the paper to the other side, like turn over a page of a book. So it means double.

I checked a couple of online dictionaries, there are for sure some misleading.

Comment: So in my sentence, '翻‘ = ’加‘。 Is that correct?

Comment: No. 翻番 is not 加番.